# Embedded C++ - Virtual destructors and heap memory

Tags: c++, embedded, heap-memory

I'm developing a bare-metal C++ program for Texas Instruments' TMS320F28054M MCU, and am building my project with the TMS320C2000 C/C++ Compiler v20.2.2.LTS. I've noticed that whenever I instantiate a class with a virtual destructor, the toolchain automatically generates an 1KB `.esysmem` section for the heap. This is strange, since I'm not actually using dynamic memory at all; in fact, this happens even when creating a variable on the stack.

Is this a compiler bug? I'm not that familiar with the innerworkings of virtual destructors, so maybe it's something to be expected.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909598/eliminating-instantiation-of-useless-destructor-calls That happened even for non virtual constructors, when I investigated about it.

Comment: What happens for virtual destructors for sure, is that a vtable will be created for the class. I can't tell how your compiler(linker) handles the auto generation of vtables.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, but that question is for gcc. Notice that this happens even when creating a variable on the stack; using a static/global variable would also generate the usual __dtors code. vtables aren't a problem, since this heap section isn't generated when I remove the virtual destructor, even if I have virtual functions, etc.

Comment: Well, legacy compilers might happen to handle that even worse than gcc does.

Comment: Whole point of those virtual destructors is to handle *deleteing* of dynamically allocated objects through pointer of base class. IOW if you do not use dynamic memory then why you need virtual destructors?

Comment: @ÖöTiib why do you care? One of C++'s philosophies is "you don't pay for what you don't use".

Comment: @Martin In an embedded context, the C++ philosophy is rather "pay in advance regardless of what you plan to use". The C++ static storage duration constructor lag at start up is a typical example of C++ creating needless overhead bloat. And then the CRT likes to run that bloat before the oscillator is initialized, turning your program slower than anything...

Comment: @martin correct we don't pay for what we don't use. So my question was  why you use virtual destructors or why you dislike to pay for what you use pointlessly?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I wasn't _using_ the virtual destructors, since at no point did I use dynamic memory in the first place. Defining something isn't the same as using it.

In this case, I had introduced the virtual destructor in the first place because it's an usual practice forced by design mistakes in the language.

Comment: @Martin How it is forced and by what mistake? When no object is ever created dynamically then destructors being virtual is waste. Even when there *are* dynamically created objects but none of those is deleted through pointer to base it is waste. And even when some *might* be deleted through pointer to base but each of such was created with make_shared then it is waste. Modern compilers aren't very frugal as memory is available 2GB per dollar ... so if economy matters then programmer has to pay attention.

Comment: @ÖöTiib are you serious? Being forced to manually add virtual destructors to make the language do the right thing is clearly a design mistake. 99% of the time you will need them, so they should be implicitly added whenever you have a virtual method. Maybe they're "a waste" in that 1% of the time, but then why isn't the compiler smart enough not to generate a gratuitous heap section? This didn't happen when adding e.g. virtual methods, only for the destructor, so it's not like it's an impossible feat.

Comment: @Martin I'm fully serious. Why I need virtual destructors? Where are dynamically allocated polymorphic objects in my C++ program (if it contains any)? All coding standards demand RAII so these are managed by standard smart pointers or managed by likes of boost::base_collection. It is rather tricky to cooperate with anyone if I don't use RAII. So if I supply deleters properly to unique_ptr's then I do not need any virtual destructors. Can you describe cases where I still need? Why?