# Get type_info from typename

Tags: c++, c++11, types, typeinfo

Is there a way to get `std::type_info` from the type's name?  For example,

```
std::type_info f(std::string name) {
std::type_info info; 
...
return info;
}

int main() {
const std::string name = typeid(double).name();
std::type_info info = f(name);
assert(info==typeid(double));
}
```

What would the function `f` be?

Comment: I suspect this is not possible, but I can't come up with a convincing reason why it wouldn't be, other than I don't know of a function that does a reverse-lookup on this information....

Comment: @Xirema: There can be no reverse lookup if the name isn't guaranteed to be different for different types.

Comment: Though you might want to use type_info elsewhere, using ````std::is_same```` is a much better approach of comparing types.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861760/what-is-the-actual-purpose-of-stdtype-infoname

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. As [documentation for `std::type_info::name`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) says:

> No guarantees are given; in particular, the returned string can be
> identical for several types and change between invocations of the same
> program.

I don't know your exact use case, but chances are you can utilise C++11 [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) instead.